# Not getting users info in the real time report in Google Analytics 4 using measurement protocol

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am using measurement protocol in GA4. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=firebase), I should see real-time users if I add session_id and engagement_time_msec as parameters in my event.

Following is the JSON body of my request.

```
{
  "user_id":"User_7xwfms",
  "app_instance_id":"a5e31b44a75401e428147618971da59d74d46265",
  "events":[
    {
      "name":"session_started",
      "params":{
        "session_id":"638295158991729126_7xwfms",
        "engagement_time_msec":1,
        "time_passed":1.007073742650463,
        "level":4,
        "target":7570164
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

​I am getting the event successfully in the GA4 real-time report, but the user count remains 0 in the "USERS IN LAST 30 MINUTES" card. Can anyone guide me on what I am doing wrong here? ​​

Comment: is this a new account?

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Yes I have tested this with several new user IDs and session IDs

Comment: if its a new account it can take a few days for it to start recording data.